# Remove JSON Element if it doesn't contain a specific value

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to return only values where john is found from a DynamoDB database.
I'm able to return values where it contains **name: john** from a mapped list, however the problem am having is that it appears to also be returning other values as well.

Running select: 'count' returns 1 match which is correct but it doesn't return anything when used.
I'm assuming that count just returns a number and not a specific select where john is matched.

I'm writing this in NodeJS; am hoping someone can help me figure this out.
I know that the value I only want shown are json elements where **name: john**, anything else I want omitted from being shown.

Here's my result as of right now:

```
{
  "Department": [
    {
      "employees": [
        {
          "name": "john"
        },
        {
          "name": "sally"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Count": 1
}
```

My code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies 
const dc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

// Construct the params for filtering data through dynamodb
const params = {
  FilterExpression: "contains(#department, :employees)",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
         "#department": "employees",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":employees": {
          "name":"john"
      }
   },
   ProjectionExpression: "#department", 
   TableName: 'mytable',
  //Select: 'COUNT'
};

const resultDC = await dc.scan(params).promise();

var items = resultDC.Items;
var count = resultDC.Count;

  var returned_list = {
    'Department' : items,
    'Count' : count,
  }; 

    // create a response
      const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(returned_list),
    };
    callback(null, response);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a Local Secondary Index.
Take a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html).